# Wrong model after z3py push but got correct model without

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I try to use Z3 on a incremental model, but I get a strange model.

When the code contains like

```
s.push()
[some calcution to get constant 4 and 3 in below 
lines]
s.add(ans6==4)
s.add(ans9==3)
```

the model comes out incorrect as

```
[ans0 = 2,
 ans1 = 3,
 ans2 = 1,
 **ans6 = 2,**
 ans8 = 2,
 ans7 = 1,
 **ans9 = 1,**
 ans4 = 1,
 ans5 = 3,
 ans3 = 3]
```

However, if I add s.add(ans6==4) as well as
s.add(ans9==3) piror to s.push(), the model is correct as unsat.

Is it a bug or I use Z3 in a wrong way? I thought it might be expressed soft constraints but the documentation didn't mention.

the full source is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from z3 import *

# ten multiple choices
ans = [Int('ans%d' % (i)) for i in range(10)]

letters = {}
for i in range(5):
    letters[i] = "0ABCD"[i]

choice_a = 1
choice_b = 2
choice_c = 3
choice_d = 4
choice_shitty = 999
choices = [choice_a, choice_b, choice_c, choice_d]

s = Solver()
for i in range(10):
    s.add(Or(ans[i] == choice_a, ans[i] == choice_b, ans[i] == choice_c, ans[i] == choice_d))

#2
s.add(Or(And(ans[1] == choice_a, ans[4] == choice_c),
         And(ans[1] == choice_b, ans[4] == choice_d),
         And(ans[1] == choice_c, ans[4] == choice_a),
         And(ans[1] == choice_d, ans[4] == choice_b)))

#3
s.add(Or(And(ans[2] == choice_a, And(ans[2] != ans[5], ans[5] == ans[1], ans[1] == ans[3])),
         And(ans[2] == choice_b, And(ans[5] != ans[2], ans[2] == ans[1], ans[1] == ans[3])),
         And(ans[2] == choice_c, And(ans[1] != ans[2], ans[2] == ans[5], ans[5] == ans[3])),
         And(ans[2] == choice_d, And(ans[3] != ans[5], ans[2] == ans[5], ans[5] == ans[1]))))

#4
s.add(Or(And(ans[3] == choice_a, ans[0] == ans[4]),
         And(ans[3] == choice_b, ans[1] == ans[6]),
         And(ans[3] == choice_c, ans[0] == ans[8]),
         And(ans[3] == choice_d, ans[5] == ans[9])))

#5
s.add(Or(And(ans[4] == choice_a, ans[4] == ans[7]),
         And(ans[4] == choice_b, ans[4] == ans[3]),
         And(ans[4] == choice_c, ans[4] == ans[8]),
         And(ans[4] == choice_d, ans[4] == ans[6])))

#6
s.add(Or(And(ans[5] == choice_a, And(ans[1] == ans[3], ans[3] == ans[7])),
         And(ans[5] == choice_b, And(ans[0] == ans[5], ans[5] == ans[7])),
         And(ans[5] == choice_c, And(ans[2] == ans[9], ans[9] == ans[7])),
         And(ans[5] == choice_d, And(ans[4] == ans[8], ans[8] == ans[7]))))

#7


#8
s.add(Or(And(ans[7] == choice_a, Not(Or(ans[0] - ans[6] == 1, ans[0] - ans[6] == -1))),
         And(ans[7] == choice_b, Not(Or(ans[0] - ans[4] == 1, ans[0] - ans[4] == -1))),
         And(ans[7] == choice_c, Not(Or(ans[0] - ans[1] == 1, ans[0] - ans[1] == -1))),
         And(ans[7] == choice_d, Not(Or(ans[0] - ans[9] == 1, ans[0] - ans[9] == -1)))))

#9
s.add(Or(And(ans[8] == choice_a, Or(And((ans[0] == ans[5]), Not(ans[5] == ans[4])), 
                                      And(Not(ans[0] == ans[5]), (ans[5] == ans[4])))),
         And(ans[8] == choice_b, Or(And((ans[0] == ans[5]), Not(ans[9] == ans[4])), 
                                      And(Not(ans[0] == ans[5]), (ans[9] == ans[4])))),
         And(ans[8] == choice_c, Or(And((ans[0] == ans[5]), Not(ans[1] == ans[4])), 
                                      And(Not(ans[0] == ans[5]), (ans[1] == ans[4])))),
         And(ans[8] == choice_d, Or(And((ans[0] == ans[5]), Not(ans[8] == ans[4]))), 
                                      And(Not(ans[0] == ans[5]), (ans[8] == ans[4])))))

#10
# max - min count

#for c in s.assertions():
#    print (c)
#s.check()
#print (s.model())

#s.add(ans[6] == 4)
#s.add(ans[9] == 3)


result = []
while True:    
    if s.check() == unsat:
        print ("no solution or search done(?)")
        print ("RESULT FOUND = ", len(result))
        break
    elif s.check() == sat:
        m = s.model()
        #print (m)        

        # prevent next model from using the SAME assignment as a previous model
        block = []
        for cond in m:
            clause = cond()
            block.append(clause != m[cond])
        #print(block)


        # special case: #7和#10
        s.push()

        cnt = {}
        for c in choices:
            cnt[c] = sum([1 for a in ans if m[a] == c])
        mincnt_choice = min(cnt, key=cnt.get)
        maxcnt_choice = max(cnt, key=cnt.get)
        mincnt = cnt[mincnt_choice]
        maxcnt = cnt[maxcnt_choice]
        diff = maxcnt - mincnt
        print ('ANSWER LETTER COUNTS： ', cnt, 'MIN： ', letters[mincnt_choice], 'MAX： ', letters[maxcnt_choice])
        print ('DIFF for #10：', diff)

        #7 
        if mincnt_choice == choice_a:
            s.add(ans[6] == choice_c)
        elif mincnt_choice == choice_b:
            s.add(ans[6] == choice_b)
        elif mincnt_choice == choice_c:
            s.add(ans[6] == choice_a)
        elif mincnt_choice == choice_d:
            s.add(ans[6] == choice_d)
        else:
            # impossible
            s.add(ans[6] == choice_shitty)


        #10
        if diff == 3:
            s.add(ans[9] == choice_a)
        elif diff == 2:
            s.add(ans[9] == choice_b)
        elif diff == 4:
            s.add(ans[9] == choice_c)
        elif diff == 1:
            s.add(ans[9] == choice_d)
        else:
            # impossible
            s.add(ans[9] == choice_shitty)

        for c in s.assertions():
            print (c)

        if s.check() == unsat:
            print ("#7/#10 constraint failed\n")
            s.pop()      

            s.add(Or(block)) 

        elif s.check() == sat:
            print ('SOLUTION: -------------------\n')
            print (m)
            #for i in range(10):
            #    sys.stdout.write (str(i+1)+". "+letters[int(str(m[ans[i]]))]+"\n")
            #print ("\n")
            result.append(m)      

            # prevent next model from using the SAME assignment as a previous model
            block = []
            for cond in m:
                clause = cond()
                block.append(clause != m[cond])
            s.pop()
            s.add(Or(block)) 
        else:
            print ("exception")
    else:
        print ("exception")
```

Comment: Without a way to reproduce this issue, it is impossible to answer what might be going wrong. Please post a minimal reproducible case of this so stack-overflow readers can point out what might be wrong. It's very unlikely z3 would get push wrong. Your code is probably doing something funky, but impossible to say without seeing the actual reproducible problem.

Comment: @alias i edited and posted up the whole source code

Comment: Can you minimize this example? Surely the behavior should exhibit itself with a much smaller program. See this for how to post a stack-overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example